# AS3 CPU performance of JPG vs PNG

Tags: image, actionscript-3, air, png, jpeg

I haven't been able to find any info on this topic.

So, in terms of runtime performance which one is better: JPG or PNG? Is there any difference? Has anyone made a test?

One aspect is how much CPU is used when loading the JPG or PNG to the BitmapData. I think both get converted to raw pixel data when loaded into a BitmapData, so JPG being a compressed format would eat more CPU cycles.

The other aspect is rendering. If indeed my intuition is right there should be no difference in rendering cost.

What do you think?

Comment: Are you after an answer that goes into as many facets as possible? For example, I suspect the difference between the two if at all would be more noticeable when copying the pixels of a transparent PNG across to a bitmap when blitting.

Comment: Yes, obviously alpha channels add more data. It should affect CPU performance... but how much?

Comment: Benchmarking is easy enough to do here, though I'm not sure how the relationship between a PNG and JPEG works; i.e. I'm not sure if a PNG of equal dimensions as a JPEG with an alpha channel is equally different when compared to PNG with no alpha channel. This might make the results of benchmarking a JPEG and PNG a little hard to relate to each other accurately.

Comment: @MartyWallace I think he's asking how much time is used to preprocess a JPG versus PNG, along with how much time is used to render a resultant bitmapdata to elsewhere. I'd say he should dump the first part, and concentrate on the second part only.

Comment: @Vesper Of course. What I mean is that although you can render both in different scenarios and test the performance of each, what is the relationship between the PNG and the JPEG and the results of each render? I suspect the PNG has more variables that affect rendering compared to the JPEG which would just come down to size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out these excellent posts of Jackson Dunstan. I made a copy of the main conclusion related to the topic:

http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/2117:

> JPEG is the fastest format to load/decompress. It’s over three times as fast as PNG

http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/2134:

> Last week’s article called PNG 3x slower to load than JPEG. However, that’s only true for ARGB (full-color) PNG. Greyscale PNG is 40% quicker and indexed is takes less than half the time of ARGB PNG.

So if you don't plan to use alpha channel it's better for CPU performance to use JPG.

Comment: Excellent. But what about rendering? Is there any difference in one or the other after decompressing?

Comment: After decompression both are BitmapData, so there isn't any difference in rendering speed, except that alpha pixels takes more resources as flash must calculates all underline pixels to get the final result.